# UIWebView always refreshes from server when navigating back

Tags: javascript, objective-c, http, caching, uiwebview

I have a website optimized for tablets. It displays a link on the page to navigate back, which calls the JavaScript function `window.history.back()`. In the Safari browser on the iPad, this link works as desired by loading the cached page from history rather than making another request to the server. However, when I open the same site through a UIWebView in a simple native app, the same link causes a request to the server each time I use it to navigate back.

I found that I could fix this by:

1. Removing the HTTP response header `Pragma: no-cache`
2. Setting the Cache-Control header to "max-age=900" (15 minutes)

However, these server-side changes appear to be necessary only for the UIWebView, and not for actual browsers like Safari and Chrome. In some cases, a native app developer will have limited or no control over the server they are calling. Therefore, it would seem preferable to have client-side control over this behavior of the UIWebView, to make it behave like mobile Safari does for this purpose. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Note that most of my testing has been done on an iPad 2.0 with iOS version 6.1.3.

Answer (score 0):

try this code for loading url in webview:

NSData *urlData;
NSString *baseURLString =  @"yoursite.com";
NSString *urlString = [baseURLString stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"yourfile"];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReturnCacheDataElseLoad timeoutInterval: 10.0]; 
NSURLConnection *connection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:nil];

if (connection)
{ 
    urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest: request];

```
NSString *htmlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[webView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:baseURLString];
[htmlString release];
```

}

[connection release];